# How to handle data with a conditional fetching via useSWR right in clickHandler?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is is possible to get data via useSWR (inside of my custom hook useGetFullProduct) and fire my function right in the click handler without useEffect?

```
const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);
const [fullProduct, error, isLoading] = useGetFullProduct(shouldFetch, brandID, 
productID);

const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShouldFetch(true);
    if (fullProduct) myFn(fullProduct)
  };
```

I need

1. get fullProduct
2. if fullProduct is not undefined fire myFn(fullProduct)

but handleClick just set flag and get data firstly and then I need to click again to run myFn. How can I do it just click one?